# How to Change Header Footer font and Color in XeLatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, header-footer, fancyhdr

I need to change the Header Footer in Latex which need to be compiled in XeLatex.

Header - Green using Lato-Light font
Footer - Red using Raleway-Light font

Here is the [link](https://www.overleaf.com/4629560gdhybg) to the MWE. Fonts are in the fonts directory. Its an editable link. Pls donot edit or compile there. You may download the Zip and test it locally and provide the solution here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that on how to write a good MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new font family like this:

```
\newfontfamily{\lato}{Lato-Light.ttf}[ExternalLocation=fonts/]
```

and then use it with

```
\fancyhead[RO]{\lato Green Header Lato font}
```

To change the text color add the package `xcolor` and set it with

```
\fancyhead[RO]{\textcolor{green}{\lato Green Header Lato font}}
```